# obtain url from login module for redirect on Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

Using Joomla 2.5 and trying to do some redirects based on the login module where you can click `Forgot your password` or `Forgot your username`.

I thought this should work for username:

```
if((JRequest::getString('option')=='com_users') && (JRequest::getString('view')=='remind'))
```

and this for password:

```
if((JRequest::getString('option')=='com_users') && (JRequest::getString('view')=='reset'))
```

I never seem to get into this if statement. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the only thing that worked for me is to use:

```
if((JRequest::getVar('option')!='com_users')
```

This covers both cases of `remind` and `reset`. Not sure if there are other edge cases where this won't match.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
if((JRequest::getVar('option')=='com_users') && (JRequest::getVar('view')=='remind'))
```

If this also failed you can try with,

`$_REQUEST['option']` it will definitely works but its not a good practice for joomla sites.